# Zend Framework - Same browser open multiple tabs but wait for first request to finished

Tags: php, apache, http, session, zend-framework2

I have issue with same browser client try to open multiple tabs with it. but my server is wait for first request to finished.

for example

1. Open first browser tab that take more time like 30sec.
2. Now, next tab open with the help of CTR + Mouse click open new tab in bowser that is just static page 1 sec wait; but stil i have to wait for first request to finished.

Note : I have website in not in live but i am using following technology 
**PHP 5.4, Mysql, Zend Framework 2.1, Xampp 1.8**

Please guide in above issue if an confution you can comment on it. I am happy to do chat also.

Comment: I think, this is because your environment is set to only one php worker process.

Comment: @DenisV - I don't think so, this is same issue with my dedicated server with 8 Core CPU, 16 GB Ram. but issue is same client and wait for first request to finished.

Comment: Well, then Sundar in his answer should be right. We had something similar in our company.

Comment: But i am using Zend 2.1 Release is that framework issue ? What do you think ?

Comment: I never worked with Zend 2.1, but I think it _can_ open the session under the hood, and as such there probably _can_ be functionality to close the session. You just need to refer to the docs. As for now there is no other good idea, then it's worth to check this first.

Comment: Ok, @DenisV Thanks a lot for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have `session_start()` on every page.

Default PHP session is based on files. Hence whenever the `session_start()` is called the file lock will occur on the server. Until complete the process the file lock won't be released.

To resolve this problem use `session_write_close()` on your page.  Use this session write close efficiently. Once you written everything into the session then close it.

session_write_close() will release the lock. After `session_write_close()` you can read the data from session but you can't write it. If you want to write it then you need to restart the session again using `session_start()`.

> Session data is usually stored after your script terminated without
>   the need to call session_write_close(), but as session data is locked
>   to prevent concurrent writes only one script may operate on a session
>   at any time. When using framesets together with sessions you will
>   experience the frames loading one by one due to this locking. You can
>   reduce the time needed to load all the frames by ending the session as
>   soon as all changes to session variables are done.

**Ref:**

http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.session-write-close.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Dear @Sundar, but my system in using Zend 2.1 Framework and i think that all take care by Zend Framwork. so, dont need to worry about session_write_close(); because that Zend\Session\Container will take care about all session store and release.

Comment: What ever the framework the same scenario. Frameworks are standard one we need customize according to our need. Kind check your entire framework the session_write_close is placed in the proper place or not

Comment: Please look into these lines ` session data is locked to prevent concurrent writes only one script may operate on a session at any time `