# Many Ajax Calls in same page - long time consuming

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using Ajax a lot, but I have problem, that so many times it doesn't work (it returns an empty string, or just hung at the server for long time with no response).

If may wait sometimes the ajax is called and getting response from server for 10 seconds, and sometimes this becomes very long time consuming, and I can wait several minutes to run a specific simple ajax call.

Here is an example of code I put at each ajax (there are two attitudes - I think I shall use the jquery always, but I want to know if my code is OK).

## Code 1: (old fashioned)

```
var tout;

function testAjax1() {
    'use strict';

    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            if (tout) {
                clearTimeout(tout);
            }
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            alert("success");
        }
    };

    function ajaxTimeout() {
        xmlhttp.abort();
        alert("timeout");
    }

    clearTimeout(tout);

    tout = setTimeout(function () {
        ajaxTimeout();
    }, 10000);

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "testAjax1.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xmlhttp.send("");
}

function ajax2, ajax3, ... ajax100 exists.
```

## Code 2: (jquery):

```
function testAjax1() {
    'use strict';
    var s;

    $.ajax({
        url : "testAjax1.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        timeout: 10000
    }).success(function (result) {
        s = result;
        alert(s);
        alert("success");
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        s = jqXHR.responseText;
        if (textStatus === "timeout") {
            alert("timeout");
        } else {
            s = jqXHR.responseText;
            alert(s);
        }
    });
}
 function ajax2, ajax3, ... ajax100 exists.
```

I use lot of ajax functions call, but:

1. I think that response from ajax1 is captured by ajax2, i.e.
2. For some reason - the responses from ajaxs functions seem too long time consuming. I don't know what - For code 1 and for code 2.

Here is the main header for jquery in html page

(I have copied the jquery into my own site)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery-1.9.1-ui.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/alljqfonts.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

<script src="./jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery/jquery-1.9.1-ui.min.js"></script>       
<script src="./jquery/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery/jquery.exif.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery/jQueryRotate.2.2.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
```

What may be wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: **Question:** Why are you running so many seperate `ajax` functions? It seems rather redundant...?

Comment: are you dealing with session in PHP files? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324994/zend-framework-same-browser-open-multiple-tabs-but-wait-for-first-request-to-f/24325186

Comment: Each ajax do other thing, and I need them. ajax1 - do login to server. ajax2 do logout. ajax3 load picture, ajax3 do PAYPAL payment , etc. General they are not running in parallel, but I don't know why is the behaviour. I am using jquery-1.8.2.min.js, jquery-1.9.1-ui.min.js for ajax.

Comment: I have dealing with session - each of my php file has session_start() in order to get enter the existing session, and use $_SESSION variable.

Comment: Sundar - I see the link you gave. Do you mean that at every php file I need to do session_write_close() at the end of it ? Does this keeps the sessions variables so I can refer them on other php (start with session_start). I need to access the variables of the sessions, nevertheless, I don't know how it is handled behind the scenes, and how can I check whether there any opened sessions, and how to kill them, or release some memory - Can it be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can not fire parallel ajax calls. Every browser has different limitations.

Solution:

Fire every ajax call on a different subdomain. Then can be parallel requests.

Comment: Generally, and perhaps always - they are not running parallel, nevertheless I think there may be another thing, that I have to clean it (in php, as Sundar said - I just want to be sure what to do - shall I use session_write_close?). I just want to solve the time consuming problem.

Comment: Also - if there is parallel running, I should avoid it. I put the code at the head of this post. I need to know what to use and whether $ajax is better, and why? (If it stands for its own - reserve all the variables. It's kind of thread, that is asynchronous, so $ajax keep it right - correct me if I am wrong. Nevertheless - is my code OK?